# How to loop over two lists to make a combination of hosts and ports

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to loop over two lists being a combinations of hosts from the inventory and ports from a variable in the task.

Given the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  children:
    kafka_broker: 
      hosts:
        server1.company.com:
        server2.company.com:
```

And the list of ports:

```yaml
[9091, 9092]
```

I am want to produce four items being the combination of those two list:

- `server1.company.com:9091`
- `server1.company.com:9092`
- `server2.company.com:9091`
- `server2.company.com:9091`

I have tried:

- using nested loops

  ```yaml
  - debug: msg=" debug msg {{ item[0] }}:{{ item[1] }}"
    with_nested:
      - groups['kafka_broker']
      - [9091, 9092]
  ```

  This gives the output:

  ```
  ok: [server1.company.com] => (item=[u"groups['kafka_broker']", 9091]) => {
      "msg": " debug msg groups['kafka_broker']:9091"
  }
  ok: [server1.company.com] => (item=[u"groups['kafka_broker']", 9092]) => {
      "msg": " debug msg groups['kafka_broker']:9092"
  }
  ok: [server2.company.com] => (item=[u"groups['kafka_broker']", 9091]) => {
      "msg": " debug msg groups['kafka_broker']:9091"
  }
  ok: [server2.company.com] => (item=[u"groups['kafka_broker']", 9092]) => {
      "msg": " debug msg groups['kafka_broker']:9092"
  }
  ```
- using `with_inventory_hostnames`

  ```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item[0] }}:{{ item[1] }}" -tls1
    with_nested:
      - with_inventory_hostnames['kafka_broker']
      - [9091, 9092]
  ```

I'm looking for an explanation why those attempts do not work as expected or a simpler solution to my problem.

Comment: Your question omitted what _is_ happening versus what you _wish_ was happening, but based solely upon the name of the made-up variable, don't you want `groups['kafka_broker']` like in the first task?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I thought I added the error.  Must have forgotten.   The first task itself gives an error - tried a few options, kept the last 2 ( one commented ).  I have now added the error to the question

Comment: Instead of just quickly downvoting the question - without giving the reason or allowing to user to correct a mistake - seems like a quick judgement without allowing to correct the issue.

Comment: Why are people recommending it to be closed?   Can you at least give a reason?

Comment: Probably because it is quite hard to understand and it seems there has been information missing before.

Comment: After editing the question, it is now clear, contains all necessary information and can be answered => it should be re-opened

Comment: Thanks @toydarian.   I can accept the comment that the question may need clarification, or more information.  But to just downvote or recommend for closing  without giving the askers an opportunity to correct doesn't  serve any useful purpose.  This site is for helping developers, not finding faults with them.   As I saw - "Not suitable for this site" by mdaniel, Zeitounator, ezkl -  It doesn't explain why it is not suitable.  This approach discourages people from asking question.  One other thing that should be kept in mind is that not every developer's first language is English.

Comment: That is why I edited it. I also voted to reopen it, as imho it is absolutely on-topic and answerable. I also added an answer that suggest how to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you.  I will be trying that shortly and will let you know,  if it is working the way I am envisioning in my playbook.  Really appreciate your help and approach to help.  I hope it gets re-opened

Comment: @adbdkb You are just doing rookie mistakes that could well be avoided by reading the documentation. `- groups['kafka_broker']` won't work because a variable have to be templated: `- "{{ groups['kafka_broker'] }}"`. Also, you are inventing things _I have tried using `with_inventory_hostnames`_, but your usage has nothing to do with [what is documented](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/inventory_hostnames_lookup.html). Your level of english have nothing to do with the downvotes, the construction of your question has.

Comment: Instead of _`code that does not work` and `code that does not work, either`_, you should construct a question with. _What I have `including existing data structure`. What I expect `including expected data structure`. Here are my trials_. This way, answerers will know the code provided in "your trials" might have non-sense. When in the way your question is written, it is hard to distinguish your trials from the problem or even from what you expect.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε - Thank you and appreciate your pointers.  I will try to formulate the questions the way you have said above.  I am a newbie in Ansible and some of the things that I tried, e.g. with _inventory_hostnames - was something I saw in some of the SO answers - and not fully knowing how some of these things work, I was trying to use them.  I would also appreciate when someone takes time to downvote or recommend close, they would take the time to add a comment with a reason.  This request is not just for me, but any SO user would appreciate that.

Comment: Well, I can understand this, but you'll have to realise that it is actually a bad idea: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a Cartesian Product of the list of hosts with the list of ports (if you have more than one host or port).
This is how you do it:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: " debug msg {{ item[0] }}:{{ item[1] }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('community.general.cartesian', groups['kafka_broker'], [9091, 9092]) }}"
```

You can also use this, which is a bit longer, but does the same

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: " debug msg {{ item[0] }}:{{ item[1] }}"
  with_community.general.cartesian:
    - "{{ groups['kafka_broker'] }}"
    - [9091, 9092]
```

If you are using ansible version 2.9 or older, you need to replace `community.general.cartesian` with `cartesian`.
Documentation of [community.general.cartesian](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/cartesian_lookup.html).

Comment: Be careful when answering with the new fully qualified syntaxes, as some users might still be on Ansible versions not accepting it

Comment: This comment is for anyone using the Cartesian lookup in Ansible 2.9.  The example in Ansible documentation - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/lookup/cartesian.html - doesn't work as is - it generates this error -  {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'lookup'. String: {{ [1, 2, 3] | lookup('cartesian', ['a', 'b']) }}"} - This is the syntax that works **lookup('cartesian', [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'])**

Comment: I usually assume, people are using the latest version, if they do not state something different on the question. @adbdkb you can use the old syntax as shown in the answer or you can upgrade to the latest version of ansible

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to use the concept and was able to use it for version 2.9.7 - my comment was more towards the official documentation for the version 2.9.7 - needs to fixed for the example, but I do not know,  how / who to contact for that